# Http POST request Error in Angular ngForm

Tags: html, angular, forms, post, single-page-application

I wanted to add new record to my MSSQL database with my Angular SPA, but when I send the form I got nothing but just error 400 - Bad Request. I think it's only SPA fault, because everything is working just fine when I test it with Postman.

My `POST` body should look like this:

```
{
    "Nazwa": "String",
    "Opis": "Another String",
    "Ownerusername": "Another String",
    "Ends": "1976-07-28"
}
```

So I made a simple model in my `eventcreator.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from '../_services/evncreator.service';
declare let alertify: any ;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-eventcreator',
  templateUrl: './eventcreator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./eventcreator.component.css']
})
  // declare let alertify;

export class EventcreatorComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = [];
  constructor(private evntservice: EventService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  evnCreate() {
    // this.model = JSON.parse(this.model);
    this.evntservice.eventCreate(this.model).subscribe(
      () => {
        alertify.success('Utworzono wydarzenie');
      },
      error => alertify.error('Wystąpił błąd')
    );
    console.log(this.model);
  }

  evnAbort() {
    window.location.href = '/';
  }
}
```

This script is using `evntservice.component.ts`, so I want to attach it too:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

@Injectable({
  // dekorator
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  eventCreate(model: any) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/Events', model);
  }

}
```

My `eventcreator.component.html` is looking like this:

```
<form #registerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="evnCreate()">
  <div class="content p-3 ml-4 mr-4 bg-white">
    <h1 class="display-2 text-dark text-center">Kreator wydarzeń</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content ml-4 mr-4 p-3 bg-warning">
      <h1 class="ml-2 mt-4 mb-4 text-center">Nazwa wydarzenia:</h1>
      <input
        class="form-control mt-3 mb-3 p-lg-4 "
        [(ngModel)]="model.Nazwa"
        name="Nazwa"
        required
      />
      <div class="text-break"></div>
      <h1 class="ml-2 mt-4 mb-4 text-center">Opis wydarzenia:</h1>
      <textarea
        class="form-control mt-3 mb-3 p-lg-4"
        required
        [(ngModel)]="model.Opis"
        name="Opis"
      ></textarea>
      <div class="text-break"></div>
      <h1 class="ml-2 mt-4 mb-4 text-center">Data wydarzenia:</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        required
        name="Ends"
        [(ngModel)]="model.Ends"
      />
      <div class="text-break"></div>
      <h1 class="ml-2 mt-4 mb-4 text-center">Organizator:</h1>
      <input
        class="form-control text-success mt-3 mb-3 p-lg-4 "
        required
        name="Ownerusername"
        [(ngModel)]="model.Ownerusername"
      />
      <div class="text-center">
        <button
          type="submit"
          class="btn mr-2 btn-success"
          (click)="evnCreate()"
        >
          Dodaj wydarzenie
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn ml-2 btn-secondary"
          (click)="evnAbort()"
        >
          Anuluj
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also, I want to include output from model and response from network monitor:

```
[Nazwa: "nlnkizcxczx", Opis: "zcxczxzxczxczcx", Ends: "2020-03-04", Ownerusername: "PanMichal"]
Nazwa: "nlnkizcxczx"
Opis: "zcxczxzxczxczcx"
Ends: "2020-03-04"
Ownerusername: "PanMichal"
```

Network monitor:

[image: Network monitor and response error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, POST body should look like **below object**:

**{
    "Nazwa": "String",
    "Opis": "Another String",
    "Ownerusername": "Another String",
    "Ends": "1976-07-28"
   }**

but you are **sending an array**

**[
  Nazwa: "nlnkizcxczx",
  Opis: "zcxczxzxczxczcx",
  Ends: "2020-03-04",
  Ownerusername: "PanMichal"
]**

- so you should try with **sending object instead of an array**.

Hope this help

Comment: How can I do that? 

I made function like that:
this.model = JSON.parse(this.model);
before this.event.eventCreate(this.model) but after that form started to sending nothing ;/

Comment: No need to parse this.model before sending to POST API call as it's already object. Try with removing JSON.parse(this.model) and send this.model directly to POST API.

Comment: I  accually tried that (look at code in question) but with that i'm just getting this error ;/

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed!**

What I did:

I replaced

```
  model: any = [];
```

To:

```
  model: any = {};
```